# How to locate the data of thin volume of LVM

Tags: linux, kernel, lvm, storage

I have a vg with pool and thin volumes. When I read the configuration, I found the extent description of 2 thin volumes are the same.

```
    thinvolume {
        id = "FjDv9Z-vUt0-S1h5-uVil-spU2-cc2L-3ZsMzG"
        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
        flags = []
        creation_time = 1697353920  # 2023-10-15 15:12:00 +0800
        creation_host = "builder"
        segment_count = 1

        segment1 {
            **start_extent = 0**
            **extent_count = 256    # 1024 Megabytes**

            type = "thin"
            thin_pool = "mythinpool"
            transaction_id = 0
            device_id = 1
        }
    }

    thin_lv {
        id = "hUNSZZ-xKQC-ItRV-1rTa-TkkY-nJxk-XqEyvA"
        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
        flags = []
        creation_time = 1697354524  # 2023-10-15 15:22:04 +0800
        creation_host = "builder"
        segment_count = 1

        segment1 {
            **start_extent = 0
            extent_count = 262144   # 1024 Gigabytes**

            type = "thin"
            thin_pool = "pool"
            transaction_id = 0
            device_id = 1
        }
    }
```

How do I determine which extents in the pool are used for a thin volume?

Thank you

Comment: Have you try `lvdisplay -m thin_lv `?

Comment: You will have to query the underlying device-mapper layer with `thin_dump`. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/915007/388397) on serverfault.